# Looping through checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox

I feel like I should know the answer but I just can't get it. I have a big form and some questions have checkboxes. I need to be able to loop through each of the checkboxes for that particular question and for the ones that're checked, I need to store in an array. I'm forced to use javascript due to working with existing code. here's one example I've tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15_0" value="Bareboat charters">
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15_1" value="charters">
<input type="checkbox" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15_2" value="Ferry">

<script>
var theForm = document.getElementById( 'OMRForm' );
var i;
var selectArray = []; //initialise empty array
for (i = 0; i < theForm.CAT_Custom_15.length; i++) {
    if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15.elements[i].type == 'checkbox'){
         if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15.elements[i].checked == true){
            selectArray.push(theForm.CAT_Custom_15.elements[i].value);
            alert(theForm.CAT_Custom_15.elements[i].value);
         }
     }
}
</script>
```

I've stared at this so long it that I'm sure i've made a mistake somewhere. Please help!

Comment: It most likely is, I've referenced them but still couldn't get my code working. Which is why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theForm.CAT_Custom_15` is itself the collection containing the `<input>`s rather than having them in an `.elements` property.

So, the `type` condition, for example, should be:

```
if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15[i].type == 'checkbox'){
```

vs.:

```
if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15.elements[i].type == 'checkbox'){
```

---

```
for (i = 0; i < theForm.CAT_Custom_15.length; i++) {
    if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15[i].type == 'checkbox'){
         if(theForm.CAT_Custom_15[i].checked == true){
            selectArray.push(theForm.CAT_Custom_15[i].value);
            alert(theForm.CAT_Custom_15[i].value);
         }
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9w9T5/

Comment: haha, I can't believe I didn't see that. That was all that's needed. I just ran a test and it's displaying all the checked checkboxes. You are a life saver man. I'll be able to make the deadline now! If we ever meet, I'll buy you a beer